# Using the same iterator multiple times in Rust

Tags: rust

> Editor's note: This code example is from a version of Rust prior to 1.0 when many iterators implemented `Copy`. Updated versions of this code produce a different errors, but the answers still contain valuable information.

I'm trying to write a function to split a string into clumps of letters and numbers; for example, `"test123test"` would turn into `[ "test", "123", "test" ]`. Here's my attempt so far:

```
pub fn split(input: &str) -> Vec<String> {
    let mut bits: Vec<String> = vec![];
    let mut iter = input.chars().peekable();
    loop {
        match iter.peek() {
            None => return bits,
            Some(c) => if c.is_digit() {
                bits.push(iter.take_while(|c| c.is_digit()).collect());
            } else {
                bits.push(iter.take_while(|c| !c.is_digit()).collect());
            }
        }
    }
    return bits;
}
```

However, this doesn't work, looping forever. It seems that it is using a clone of `iter` each time I call `take_while`, starting from the same position over and over again. I would like it to use the same `iter` each time, advancing the same iterator over all the `each_time`s. Is this possible?

Comment: For what it's worth, as of 2/2015 `Peekable<Chars>` is not a `Copy`, so the original code doesn't loop infinitely -- it throws a compile error indicating an ownership change on calling `take_while`. See, for example: http://is.gd/1ppVX0

Answer (score 16, accepted):

As you identified, each `take_while` call is duplicating `iter`, since `take_while` takes `self` and the `Peekable` chars iterator is [`Copy`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/master/std/kinds/trait.Copy.html). (**Only true before Rust 1.0 — editor**)

You want to be modifying the iterator each time, that is, for `take_while` to be operating on an `&mut` to your iterator. Which is exactly what the [`.by_ref`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.by_ref) adaptor is for:

```
pub fn split(input: &str) -> Vec<String> {
    let mut bits: Vec<String> = vec![];
    let mut iter = input.chars().peekable();
    loop {
        match iter.peek().map(|c| *c) {
            None => return bits,
            Some(c) => if c.is_digit(10) {
                bits.push(iter.by_ref().take_while(|c| c.is_digit(10)).collect());
            } else {
                bits.push(iter.by_ref().take_while(|c| !c.is_digit(10)).collect());
            },
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    println!("{:?}", split("123abc456def"))
}
```

Prints

```
["123", "bc", "56", "ef"]
```

However, I imagine this is not correct.

I would actually recommend writing this as a normal `for` loop, using the [`char_indices`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.str.html#method.char_indices) iterator:

```
pub fn split(input: &str) -> Vec<String> {
    let mut bits: Vec<String> = vec![];
    if input.is_empty() {
        return bits;
    }

    let mut is_digit = input.chars().next().unwrap().is_digit(10);
    let mut start = 0;

    for (i, c) in input.char_indices() {
        let this_is_digit = c.is_digit(10);
        if is_digit != this_is_digit {
            bits.push(input[start..i].to_string());
            is_digit = this_is_digit;
            start = i;
        }
    }

    bits.push(input[start..].to_string());
    bits
}
```

This form also allows for doing this with much fewer allocations (that is, the `String`s are not required), because each returned value is just a slice into the `input`, and we can use lifetimes to state this:

```
pub fn split<'a>(input: &'a str) -> Vec<&'a str> {
    let mut bits = vec![];
    if input.is_empty() {
        return bits;
    }

    let mut is_digit = input.chars().next().unwrap().is_digit(10);
    let mut start = 0;

    for (i, c) in input.char_indices() {
        let this_is_digit = c.is_digit(10);
        if is_digit != this_is_digit {
            bits.push(&input[start..i]);
            is_digit = this_is_digit;
            start = i;
        }
    }

    bits.push(&input[start..]);
    bits
}
```

All that changed was the type signature, removing the `Vec<String>` type hint and the `.to_string` calls.

One could even write an iterator like this, to avoid having to allocate the `Vec`. Something like `fn split<'a>(input: &'a str) -> Splits<'a> { /* construct a Splits */ }` where `Splits` is a struct that implements `Iterator<&'a str>`.

Comment: Oh, this `by_ref` saved me!

Answer (score 5):

`take_while` takes `self` by value: it consumes the iterator. Before Rust 1.0 it also was unfortunately able to be implicitly copied, leading to the surprising behaviour that you are observing.

You cannot use `take_while` for what you are wanting for these reasons. You will need to manually unroll your `take_while` invocations.

Here is one of many possible ways of dealing with this:

```
pub fn split(input: &str) -> Vec<String> {
    let mut bits: Vec<String> = vec![];
    let mut iter = input.chars().peekable();
    loop {
        let seeking_digits = match iter.peek() {
            None => return bits,
            Some(c) => c.is_digit(10),
        };
        if seeking_digits {
            bits.push(take_while(&mut iter, |c| c.is_digit(10)));
        } else {
            bits.push(take_while(&mut iter, |c| !c.is_digit(10)));
        }
    }
}

fn take_while<I, F>(iter: &mut std::iter::Peekable<I>, predicate: F) -> String
where
    I: Iterator<Item = char>,
    F: Fn(&char) -> bool,
{
    let mut out = String::new();
    loop {
        match iter.peek() {
            Some(c) if predicate(c) => out.push(*c),
            _ => return out,
        }
        let _ = iter.next();
    }
}

fn main() {
    println!("{:?}", split("test123test"));
}
```

This yields a solution with two levels of looping; another valid approach would be to model  it as a state machine one level deep only. Ask if you aren’t sure what I mean and I’ll demonstrate.

Comment: I want to mention that the `itertools` crate provides a `peeking_take_while` method which does essentially what this answer's function does, but in a generic fashion.